# Knockout observable - passing additional data in callback?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I have a complex object that I wrap in a KnockoutObservable so various areas of the code can subscribe and be notified when this object changes.  For example:

```
var myObj: KnockoutObservable<MyObj> = ko.observable(null).extend({ notify: 'always' });
...
// other code
myObj.subscribe(function(myObj: MyObj) {
    // myObj changed
});
...
myObj(myObjNew);
```

However ideally I'd like to pass an additional object to all observers with some details about what exactly changed on the complex object.  For example:

```
var myObj: KnockoutObservable<MyObj> = ko.observable(null).extend({ notify: 'always' });
...
// other code
myObj.subscribe(function(myObj: MyObj, changed: any) {
    if (changed.field1) {
        // myObj.field1 changed
    }
});
...
myObj(myObjNew, { field1: 'a'});
```

Is there a way I could pass additional info like this when setting a KnockoutObservable so each of the subscribers gets not only the latest value, but also this additional info?

Comment: Knockout doesn't track *what* changed, only that *something* changed. The only real solution is to make the actual properties observable rather than the object that  combines them. You might want to look at the knockout mapping plugin if you want to do this automatically.

Comment: Yeah I know it doesn't.  And I've looked into that mapping plugin as well.  I was just trying to see if there was a way to pass additional data when setting an observable value so that data could be propagated to the callbacks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to send extra data when updating the observable?If it is just an object, add a new property to the data and store the changes in the object, no need to send "extra" data when updating the observable. If you can already get the "extra" data there's no reason it can't just be appended to the object every time you update it.

Then all you have to do is read the myObj().updatedFields property or whatever you name it.